# Redirect URI not working with DeferredResult<ResponseEntity>

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-async

Below is code sample which I am using to response back for this API.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/transactionStatusAsync")
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> asyncTransactionStatus(HttpServletRequest request, Model model,
        Locale locale, HttpServletResponse response) {
    LOGGER.info("Request received async-deferredResult TransactionStatus request");
    //return generateDeferredAndProcessRequest(request, response);
    DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<?>> output = new DeferredResult<>();
    output.setResult(createResponseEntity(ERROR_PAGE,
            HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT));
    return output ;
}

private static ResponseEntity<?> createResponseEntity(String path, HttpStatus status) {
    URI location = URI.create(path); **// "/WEB-INF/views/jsp/error.jsp"**
    boolean absolute = location.isAbsolute(); **//false**
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setLocation(location);
    ResponseEntity<?> objectResponseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(responseHeaders, status);
    return objectResponseEntity ;
}
```

NOTE: URI is a relative one not absolute URI.

Error coming as : HTTP ERROR 408   (This page isn't working)

Although, my response with **DeferredResult**  is working fine when I am writing bytes in response body like below: 
        output.setResult(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(responseData.getBytes()));

What should I do to response back particular URI in deferred response ?

Answer (score 0):

`HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT` is the HTTP error code 408.
The `location` header is considered only for 3xx (redirection) or 201 (created) status responses.

I.e. you need to change the status to `HttpStatus.FOUND` (302) for your code to work.